# Generating PDF from PhpMyAdmin database with FPDF throws 'Cannot access 'self' when no class scope is active' error

Tags: database, pdf, phpmyadmin

right now I'm working with FPDF to create a PHPmyadmin database to a PDF, but I'm stuck with this error.

The imprimirPDF.php:

```
<?php

require("fpdf185/fpdf.php");
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B', 13);
$pdf->Cell(0,10, 'Listado de peliculas', 0, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Ln(15);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B', 10);

// fragmento de adición de datos a la tabla

// call a query to get all the data from the table
$stmt = self::$dbh->query("select * from peliculas");
    
$tpelis = [];
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Pelicula');
while ( $peli = $stmt->fetch()){
    $tpelis[] = $peli;   
    $pdf->Cell(20,10, 'Codigo', 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell( $peli->$codigo_pelicula, 1, 0, 'C' );
    $pdf->Cell(60,10, 'Nombre', 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell( $peli->$nombre, 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(60,10, 'Director', 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell( $peli->$director, 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(40,10, 'Genero', 1, 0, 'C');  
    $pdf->Cell( $peli->$genero, 1, 0, 'C');  
}
return $tpelis;

// ----------------------------------------------------


$pdf->Output();

?>
```

The main error is "Cannot access "self" when no class scope is active in ...".
If anyone know how to fix this I will be very grateful. If more code is needed I'll add more code snippets.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access "self" when no class scope is active in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pelisapp\app\plantilla\imprimir\imprimirPDF.php:14 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Pelisapp\app\controlerPeli.php(126): include_once() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Pelisapp\index.php(54): ctlPeliImprimirPDF() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pelisapp\app\plantilla\imprimir\imprimirPDF.php on line 14

I tried all the combinations to fix this which I found on the web, but none of them worked for me.